# Datatables processing message location when no scrollbar

Tags: datatables

Version: 1.1.20, Chrome

I notice that when there are not enough rows shown to make the vertical scroll bar appear that the processing message's location is over top of the column headers.

Any suggestions on how to specifically set the location when the scroll bar isn't present such as the middle of the browser screen?

[image]

Even vertically centering it on the entire datatable would be fine.

Let me better explain the situation. Initially on page load I wasn't loading any rows and only grabbing the total row count from the DB. During this query for row count the DataTable displays the Processing message over top of the column headers and is difficult to notice which is what my image is showing.

But now I think it would be easier to not to return the total rows until the user performs a search. This would cause the Processing message to blink or even not appear.

Comment: if I'm not wrong you always want scrollbar in the middle of the browser screen?

Comment: Can you provide some more details, so we can help you? I have never seen this behavior, myself. For example: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue? What is your DataTables definition? How can we reproduce this issue for ourselves? What have you done to try to solve this yourself? All that info would be helpful - thanks!

Comment: Where is the code that reproduces the problem? We can't debug an idea.